# Looping through re-seach-forward gives error

Tags: search

This program aims to restore the guile REPL session dump (see input file).

When I added the while loop, ELISP stated giving me this error when the end of the file is reacher:

`Scan error: "Containing expression ends prematurely", 715, 716`

Can someone please tell me what the problem is?

This is the program:

## PROGRAM

```lisp
(defun retore-guile-session()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion 
  (while (progn (re-search-forward "scheme@(guile-user)" (point-max) t))
     (append-to-buffer "scratch" (find-start-of-sexp)
                                 (find-end-of-sexp)))))



(defun find-start-of-sexp ()

   (re-search-forward "(" (point-max) t)
   (backward-char) 
   (point-marker))


(defun find-end-of-sexp ()
  (forward-sexp)
  (point-marker))
```

And this is the input file?

## INPUT FILE

```
GNU Guile 2.0.11
Copyright (C) 1995-2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Guile comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY; for details type `,show w'.
This program is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions; type `,show c' for details.

Enter `,help' for help.
scheme@(guile-user)> 
scheme@(guile-user)> 
scheme@(guile-user)> 
scheme@(guile-user)> (+ 1 2)
$2 = 3
scheme@(guile-user)> 
scheme@(guile-user)> 
scheme@(guile-user)> (+1 2)
ERROR: In procedure 1:
ERROR: Wrong type to apply: 1

Entering a new prompt.  Type `,bt' for a backtrace or `,q' to continue.
scheme@(guile-user) [1]> 
scheme@(guile-user) [1]> 
scheme@(guile-user) [1]> (+ 1 2 (*
                 2 3))
$3 = 9
scheme@(guile-user) [1]>
```

Can someone please tell me, why is ELISP giving me error `Scan error: "Containing expression ends prematurely", 715, 716` when the while loop reaches the end of the file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In case of errors, activate `debug-on-error` (you can use `M-x toggle-debug-on-error`) to get a backtrace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specified `t` for the no-error argument of `re-search-forward` in `find-start-of-sexp`. This is the case where `re-search-forward` just returns `nil` if there is no match. Note, that point is *not* moved in this case.

The last occurrence of `scheme@(guile-user)` is not followed by a sexp embraced by parenthesis. Therefore, the search for `(` fails and point remains behind `scheme@(guile-user)`.

After the search you go one char backwards in `find-start-of-sexp` and end up before the `)` of `scheme@(guile-user)`. Therefore, the next `forward-sexp` naturally fails and gives the scan error you wonder about.

One easy cure of the problem would be to replace `t` in `re-search-forward` by some other non-nil symbol like `'noerr`. In this case point would be placed at end of buffer if the search fails. But, I wonder whether this is what you really want. For an example: What happens with the first occurrences of `scheme@(guile-user)`? The next pair of parenthesis are the argument delimiters of the next `scheme@(guile-user)`!